# Azure Graph - Graph query to retrieve App Service Plan (Microsoft.Web/serverfarms) CPU%

Tags: azure, azure-web-apps

I need to do some consolidation on my company's Azure estate, especially around App Service Plans.

In the past, we would typically create a new App Service Plan for each service we deployed as this would aid us with departmental cross-charging as each ASP would be tagged with each department's cost code.

We now have a massive sprawl of ASPs and I suspect none of them are probably running anywhere near capacity, even at S1 level so we're now looking to a more simplified model. We probably also have over-scaled ASPs that we planned but are never actually needed.

Not ever having used Graph Explorer (in anger) can someone please point me in the right direction on where I can find the CPU% instrument data so that I can execute a query to pull this data out.

I know you can "share -> download" from each individual ASP but with the amount of ASPs we have, doing that manually would take forever to do

Once I have that data locally, I can then some basic "what-if" scenarios on around consolidating ASPs and get more cost efficient with our Azure spending.

Thanks.

Comment: You probably won't be able to use resource graph explorer for something like that. Assuming you're sending logs to a log analytics workspace for all your ASPs, you'll need to query log analytics and get logs from there - is that something you've already considered?

Comment: @KedMardemootoo TBH, No it is not something I have considered because, actually, I currently don't know how to or where the data would get logged - Any suggestions on where to start looking ... My primary role is a developer and I leave all the Azure deployments to our platform team ... but they're no help here